# is there any way to see which route matched a request from the browser in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, routes

In my **routes.rb** file I have a number of routes. I would like to know which one got matched for any request a user may have made.

For example, in routes.rb you have the following routes :

```
map.connect ":controller/:action"
map.connect ":controler/:action/:id"
```

and if I have a controller named **a** and an action named **first**, when a user goes to **http://whatever/a/first** , I would like to see that the **:controller/:action** route was picked.

Can I do that for any request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know which controller/action you're in, the controller provides `controller_name` and `action_name` methods. So you might do something like this:

```
# in application_controller.rb
before_filter :set_where_am_i
def set_where_am_i
  @where_am_i = "#{controller_name}/#{action_name}"
end

# in views/layouts/application.erb, somewhere in your html
# (here I choose the <title>)

<head><title>Here: <%= @where_am_i %></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could find was in the log files. You will see for each request which action of which controller matched. 
You will see something like this :

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"2", "controller"=>"mycontroller"}
```

From there, it should be easy,right?

Comment: Yea, if you're watching the logs things get a whole lot easier. My answer still explains how to get it in the browser if you'd prefer that.